# Jupyter Lab: Matplotlib live plot is scaled awkwardly

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I want to implement some live plotting in Jupyter lab using [Jupyter-Matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib). Unfortunately the plot is scaled awkwardly during live plotting. You can see the result in the GIF below. Only the upper left corner of the plot is visible.

[image]

The code I used is as follows:

```
%matplotlib notebook
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import time

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
canvas = fig.canvas

a = []
for i in range(10):
    a.append(i)
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(a)
    canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Does anyone have experience with this kind of issue and knows how to fix it?

Comment: The app may not have enough time to properly scale before falling a`sleep`. (More generally, `sleep` is never a good idea in interactive apps). Did you consider using a `FuncAnimation`, just as everyone else?

Comment: Yes I was considering using FuncAnimation and it fact it works. It is a little inconvenient, though.